# How to post the values from the input field using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and I'm creating group component where I'm giving name, email, member emails as an input and posting the data using API but the problem is while posting the data, it is showing 400 error (bad request).

Here is the code, which I have done:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      mail: "",
      description: "",
      memberemails: ""
    };
  }
  handleChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      mail: this.state.mail,
      description: this.state.description,
      memberemails: this.state.memberemails
    };
    axios
      .post(`/api/groups`, data, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Field
            control={Input}
            label="Group Name"
            name="name"
            value={this.state.name}
            placeholder="Group Name"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />

          <Form.Field
            control={TextArea}
            label="Group Description"
            name="description"
            value={this.state.description}
            placeholder="What is this group for..."
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />

          <Form.Field
            control={Input}
            label="Group Mail"
            name="mail"
            value={this.state.mail}
            placeholder="Group Mail"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />

          <Form.Field
            control={Input}
            label="Add Members"
            placeholder="Search In Your Contacts..."
            name="memberMails"
            value={this.state.memberemails}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />

          <Button inverted color="green" animated>
            <Button.Content visible>Submit</Button.Content>
            <Button.Content hidden>
              <Icon name="send" />
            </Button.Content>
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

code: "https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-glitter-65y41"

JSON data would be like this:

```
{
  "Id": "3f66afa6",
  "name": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "mail": "string",
  "memberemails": "string"
}
```

***Issues***:

1. Unable to write more words in Description input field.
2. In mail input field I want to suffix @abc.com after the input value.
3. 400 bad request.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: I think the data you are passing to the ```api``` call might have issues.. You need to check with backend team for the format of the data they need as an input for this request..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - I've checked in swagger, it is working fine. But through the component, i could not able to send the data

Comment: The api call which you have mentioned is local api or available public?? I am asking to check with the api with the react code you have provided.. Instead of ```/api/groups```  like ```https://api.github.com/users``` ..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan -  API which i have provided is local API

Comment: Then its really hard to say what is going wrong there.. I would say check with postman tool with your local ```api``` call and the inputs your are passing to your ```api``` call..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - Yes there is a problem in API. Thank you so much for helping me. I thought it was my mistake from my end. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Glad to help you Sandhya.. If any such issues came in future, then be sure that you check for necessary details with the team who creates that ```api```..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - 3rd issue this is resolved. Could you please help me with the 2nd issue?

Comment: Regarding your second issue, what if user itself types email like ```xyz@abc.com``` ?? If  we suffix ```@abc.com``` and user enters ```xyz@abc.com``` then it will form like this ```xyz@abc.com@abc.com``` which is not right..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - Yes, even i'm also getting in this way xyz@abc.com@abc.com. Is there any other option to make this thing possible?

Comment: We can only check if the user entered text matches with email ```regex``` for that you can check this example https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/QWbKZKG but based on my understanding the suffix part and all its too complex to maintain..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - Okay